# Spark Core How to fetch max n rows of an RDD function without using Rdd.max()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an *RDD* having below elements:

```
('09', [25, 66, 67])
('17', [66, 67, 39])
('04', [25])
('08', [120, 122])
('28', [25, 67])
('30', [122])
```

I need to fetch the elements having a max number of elements in the list which is 3 in the above RDD O/p should be filtered into another RDD and not use the *max function* and **spark dataframes**:

```
('09', [25, 66, 67])
('17', [66, 67, 39])
```

```
max_len = uniqueRDD.max(lambda x: len(x[1]))
maxRDD = uniqueRDD.filter(lambda x : (len(x[1]) == len(max_len[1])))
```

I am able to do with the above lines of code but spark streaming won't support this as max_len is a tuple and not RDD

Can someone suggest? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? I tried filtering on the streaming rdds as well. Seems to work.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,1)



data1 = [
    ('09', [25, 66, 67]),
    ('17', [66, 67, 39]),
    ('04', [25]),
    ('08', [120, 122]),
    ('28', [25, 67]),
    ('30', [122])
]


df1Columns = ["id", "list"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)
df1.show(20, truncate=False)

uniqueRDD = df1.rdd


max_len = uniqueRDD.map(lambda x: len(x[1])).max(lambda x: x)
maxRDD = uniqueRDD.filter(lambda x : (len(x[1]) == max_len))

print("printing out maxlength = ", max_len)

dStream = ssc.queueStream([uniqueRDD])

resultStream = dStream.filter(lambda x : (len(x[1]) == max_len))

print("Printing the filtered streaming result")

def printResultStream(rdd):
    mylist = rdd.collect()
    for ele in mylist:
        print(ele)

resultStream.foreachRDD(printResultStream)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
ssc.stop()
```

Here's output :

```
+---+------------+
|id |list        |
+---+------------+
|09 |[25, 66, 67]|
|17 |[66, 67, 39]|
|04 |[25]        |
|08 |[120, 122]  |
|28 |[25, 67]    |
|30 |[122]       |
+---+------------+

printing out maxlength =  3
Printing the filtered streaming result
Row(id='09', list=[25, 66, 67])
Row(id='17', list=[66, 67, 39])
```

You can try something like this:

```
dStream = ssc.queueStream([uniqueRDD, uniqueRDD, uniqueRDD])
def maxOverRDD(input_rdd):
    if not input_rdd.isEmpty():
        reduced_rdd = input_rdd.reduce(lambda acc, value : value if (len(acc[1]) < len(value[1])) else acc)
        internal_result = input_rdd.filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) == len(reduced_rdd[1]))
        return internal_result


result = dStream.transform(maxOverRDD)
print("Printing the finalStream")
result.foreachRDD(printResultStream)
```

Output would be like (Output is repeated because the same RDD is provided 3 times in the stream):

```
Printing the finalStream
Row(id='09', list=[25, 66, 67])
Row(id='17', list=[66, 67, 39])
Row(id='09', list=[25, 66, 67])
Row(id='17', list=[66, 67, 39])
Row(id='09', list=[25, 66, 67])
Row(id='17', list=[66, 67, 39])
```

Comment: can you please share then spark streaming code ?

Comment: can we do this in TransformedDStream?
My requirement is to do everything in streams and not RDD
please see the code below :
```
maxDStream = uniqueDStream.map(lambda x: len(x[1])).max(lambda x: x)
maxRDDDstream = uniqueDStream.filter(lambda x: (len(x[1]) == maxDStream))
```
getting an error :

Comment: Hi @Prashant, please avoid asking more and more questions in the comments deviating from your original question. If you have a new question feel free to open a new question. Otherwise it can become quite frustrating to answer your questions.

Comment: @Prashant : Edit the question properly with all the `relevant` details. Along with code samples on what you want to do.

Comment: I need to do everything in Streaming context only.
<br/>  Wrote below code :
<br/>  
maxDStream = uniqueDStream.map(lambda x: len(x[1])).max(lambda x: x)
maxRDDDstream = uniqueDStream.filter(lambda x: (len(x[1]) == maxDStream))

<br>  
getting below error :

maxDStream = uniqueDStream.map(lambda x: len(x[1])).max(lambda x: x)
maxRDDDstream = uniqueDStream.filter(lambda x: (len(x[1]) == maxDStream))

Comment: @user238607, can you please assist

Comment: @Prashant : As the stream gets more RDDs, the max over those will change. Do you want the max to be calculated for the same RDD and applied on it?

Comment: yes @user238607 thats okay as streams will arrive individually in single window. so i need max for for a file in 1 window.

Comment: @Prashant : I have edited the function `maxOverRDD` as from `value[1]` to `value`. Please correct it in your code. It might throw any error on different data. So please note.

Comment: ok thanks ! i have another query related to spark structured streaming , can you please help there ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129266/spark-structure-streaming-group-by-aggregation